# Get data between January to March in the past 4 years

Tags: sql, oracle

I've data of last 4 years that is 2018,2019,2020,2021.
Out of this I need data from JANUARY TO MARCH in all 2018,2019,2020,2021.

I can write date between four times.
But I don't want the query to look very big. So in a single query how to get that data

Answer (score 2):

If there's a `DATE` datatype column (should be; let's call it `datum`), then you could e.g.

```
select *
from your_table
where extract(year from datum) in (2018, 2019, 2020, 2021)
  and extract(month from datum) in (1, 2, 3)
order by datum;
```

---

If you stored dates as strings (into a `VARCHAR2` column), then first convert it to a valid `date` datatype value using the `TO_DATE` function with appropriate format model.

For example, if values are stored as 20220715 (which is `yyyymmdd`),

```
to_date(datum, 'yyyymmdd')
```

The rest of query is just the same:

```
select *
from your_table
where extract(year from to_date(datum, 'yyyymmdd')) in ...
```

Beware! Oracle doesn't handle strings as dates! There might be invalid values in that column, e.g. "20ac#713"; applying `to_date` to it will raise error (as that's obviously not a date). Or, if there were "20220230" (30th of February), you'll get error again.

**Always** store dates into `date` datatype columns!

Comment: What if the date is just varchar2 datatype

Comment: Convert it to date first; see edited answer.

Comment: In case if there's a calendar_day column with values like 2018-10-02, 2021-08-09 and net_revenue_usd column like 10,146 and we want to derive net_sales_value = net_revenue_usd (only when calendar_day between 1-jan and 12-mar for all years like 2018,2019,2020,2021)